# Can I deploy Playwright browsers with my application

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side, playwright

The Playwright library is, thus far, the only library that I have found with which I can scrape my Blazor Server site (for building an index for an internal search engine). Selenium doesn't appear to like the dynamic DOM, curl and Invoke-WebRequest just return an empty BODY tag and some JS (because it's not actually rendered until the client runs the JS). But Playwright works beautifully. It sees the DOM and I can get my static text from my pages.

To enact this, I have a page set up where, if I hit it with Invoke-WebRequest or curl, it will process all of my search data and index it. This works great when browsers are installed properly.

But it appears that it was not only intended for use in a CI pipeline, but that use is also enforced by various methodologies. For instance, there does not appear to be a straightforward way to manually install browsers in a deployment scenario. It has to be done via the powershell script that gets put into the bin folder on build. But in order to run that script, the csproj files must be present, which clearly isn't going to be the case after deployment.

There appears to be a way to install them by calling the Main method in the Playwright DLL, but that doesn't appear to work on my target system (Ubuntu 18.04) and there are no error messages, just an exit code that doesn't appear to have any documentation that I've found, thus far.

Is there an effective way, in an automated fashion, to ensure that Playwright browsers are installed on a target deployment system?

Comment: If that is not something that is really feasible, then I am open to other methodologies to achieve my end goal of scraping my Blazor site.

1. An alternative to Playwright that can read the dynamic DOM from my Blazor site.
2. An alternative workflow for generating my index.

For #2, I am considering the following:
- Build and deploy the main site
- Build a secondary utility that generates the index files by hitting the (now live) site and publishes them to the appropriate location.

Comment: I did not - it wasn't specifically related to the exact question, and was intended to be ancillary to it. I thought a comment would be most appropriate.